# How to use parameters in a function to dynamically calculate, and return values from independent functions

Tags: javascript, sum, alert, multiplication, prompt

I am trying to create a function in JavaScript that does basic calculations, but the function has to capture return values from other independent functions that do addition, multiplication, and remainder division/modulo.

The result will be shown in an `alert()` method, below code is working well but I think it should be simpler code than what I have!

Other functions get the value from the user with the `prompt()` method, but I am repeating the prompt 3 times, can I have a function that takes values once and pass to other functions for calculations.

```js
function var_ops_3add() {
  var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter First Number"));
  var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter Second Number"));
  return (c = a + b);
}
function var_ops_3multiply() {
  var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter First Number"));
  var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter Second Number"));
  return (d = a * b);
}
function var_ops_3module() {
  var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter First Number"));
  var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter Second Number"));
  return (e = a % b);
}
function var_ops_3() {
  var_ops_3add();
  var_ops_3multiply();
  var_ops_3module();
  alert("Addition = " + c);
  alert("Multiplication = " + d);
  alert("Module = " + e);
}

var_ops_3();
```

Comment: Not sure what you're even asking. Is it around how to take in parameters and return values? [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Comment: @AlienWithPizza I am trying to create a simple calculator into a complex multi-functions method. Below specialized_Rider answer solves my question, I was missing the 'keywork' Parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
  function var_ops_3add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }
  function var_ops_3multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b;
  }
  function var_ops_3module(a, b) {
    return a % b;
  }
  function var_ops_3() {
    var a = parseInt(prompt("Enter First Number"));
    var b = parseInt(prompt("Enter Second Number"));
    alert("Addition = " + var_ops_3add(a, b));
    alert("Multiplication = " + var_ops_3multiply(a, b));
    alert("Module = " + var_ops_3module(a, b));
  }
  
  var_ops_3();
```

Use var a, b as parameters for the calculation functions

Answer (score -1):

```js
function prompter(title, fn) {
  const a = parseInt(prompt("Enter First Number"), 10);
  const b = parseInt(prompt("Enter Second Number"), 10);
  return alert(title + ' = ' + fn(a, b));
}

prompter('Addition', (a, b) => a + b);
prompter('Multiplication', (a, b) => a * b);
prompter('Modulo', (a, b) => a % b);
```

Comment: Thanks Eric but I needed independent functions doing the calculation and return value capture and display in a single function.